# How to use a Web Worker in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, factory, web-worker, worker, angular-services

I'm using [AngularJS Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) and I want to see a working implementation of a Web Worker.

I want to make a simple Web Worker work in order to understand it, but I'm running into an issue with the functionality.

I have the Web Worker code in the **services.js** like so:

```
'use strict';

/* Services */
var app = angular.module('myApp.services', []).

app.factory("HelloWorldService",['$q',function($q){

    var worker = new Worker('js/doWork.js');
    var defer;
    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
      defer.resolve(e.data);
    }, false);

    return {
        doWork : function(myData){
            defer = $q.defer();
            worker.postMessage(myData); // Send data to our worker. 
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };

}]);
```

In the **js** folder I have a file **doWork.js** and its contents are:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

My **controllers.js** file is empty and it looks like so:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
var app = angular.module("myApp.controllers",[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl1', [ '$scope', function($scope) {


}]).controller('MyCtrl2', [ '$scope', function($scope) {


}]);
```

**What I want is to see the output of the Web Worker.**

The error I get with this setup is:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'factory' of undefined*

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error?

change

```
/* Services */
var app = angular.module('myApp.services', []).
```

to

```
/* Services */
var app = angular.module('myApp.services', []);
```

Comment: I fixed that error, thanks! No errors anymore, but I still don't see the message from my Web Worker. Nothing pops up in the console that would verify that the Web Worker did something.

Comment: Have you told the worker to do anything? It may be just sitting and waiting for you. You need to inject your $HelloWorldService into a controller and call $HelloWorldService.doWork( "something" ) .

`app.controller('MyCtrl1', [ '$scope', '$HelloWorldService', function($scope, $HelloWorldService) {
$HelloWorldService.doWork("something");

}]).controller('MyCtrl2', [ '$scope', function($scope) {


}]);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have something to resolve the promise returned from your service. Something along the lines of

```
var promise = HelloWorldService.doWork( input );
promise.then( function( allWentGoodMessage ){
    // green path code goes here
}, function( somethingWentBadMessage ){
    // error handling code goes here
} );
```

Also, you'll need to inject the service into the controller that calls the service.

Take a look at [this post](http://www.codingterminal.com/articles/092014/1/XMLHttpRequest%20using%20AngularJS%20Promises%20and%20HTML5%20Web%20Workers.html) for another way of dealing with web workers in AngularJS.

And you might also want to get acquainted with the promise implementation, [`$q` in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)